# Lambda expression throws System.MissingMemberException

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda, windows-phone-8.1

I have a lambda function defined inside a class which throws System.MissingMemberException on runtime.

```
Module Res         
    Public Class LAMBDAS            
        Public Shared add1 = Function(num As Integer) num + 1    
    End Class    
End Module
```

When a call this like from another class

```
Private Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim r = LAMBDAS.add1(12)
End Sub
```

It throws exception

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in
>   MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No default member found for type
>   'VB$AnonymousDelegate_1(Of Integer,Integer)'.

But, If I include the lambda inside the second class it works fine.

```
Dim add1 = Function(num As Integer) num + 1
Dim r = add1(12)
```

Is it not possible to add lambda functions inside other modules and classes?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the module but keep Class LAMBDAS?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I had a similar problem which made me scratch my head for an hour or so before fixing it.

If you check the type of add1 in the debugger you will see it is an object rather than a lambda function, so the compiler automatically thinks that you are trying to index a default property rather than run a piece of code.

To resolve it you can do the following:

```
Module Res         
    Public Class LAMBDAS            
        Public Shared add1 As Func(Of Integer) = Function(num As Integer) num + 1    
    End Class    
End Module
```